# Nvidia Jetson TX1 opencv4tegra cmake example

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, nvidia

I've just unboxed a new NVIDIA Jetson TX1 dev kit, and I'm looking forward to seeing how the hardware accelerated algorithms in the opencv4tegra library fare against standard opencv.  Does anyone have an example CMakeLists.txt file for compiling with the NVIDIA library.

Assume I have source in a file `vision.cpp`.  What would the basic CMakeLists.txt file look like to compile and link it against the opencv4tegra library?

Comment: do you want to cross-compile or compile on the jetson?